# Client-side generated charts for use in job for sending reports

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radchart

Client is asking us for replacement of Telerik's RadChart control with its new HTML5 version - RadHtmlChart. The problem is that all of reporting emails stuff is working on that control because charts are generated on server side and it's fine to use them for sending reports emails to users.

So now after we'll replace RadChart with RadHtmlChart we will lose a possibility to get a chart on server side. Is there any way to get that report?

I have heard about PhantomJS which could do the job but I'm not very familiar with that idea so I'm asking to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Exporting a control that is rendered via JS in the browser is difficult and may not be possible in your scenario. Take a look here to see if you can employ this approach: http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/exporting-radhtmlchart-to-png-and-pdf. If you cannot - I think you will have to keep using RadChart to get actual images rendered.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sometimes it's really hard to explain a client something like that :)

Comment: I am not sure exactly how and what you need to generate, but perhaps you will find useful PhantomJS - it can help you render a page on the server and produce an image that you can embed: http://phantomjs.org/. I just stumbled upon it and remembered this thread.